# Upper bound of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> I need to find the upper bound of the function $f(x,y)=x(y-x-1)e^{-y}$ on $A=\{(x,y)\mid 0\le x\le y\}$.

So $f_{x}=e^{-y}(y-2x-1)$ and $f_{y}=xe^{-y}(x-y+2)$ and critical points are: $(0,1)$ and $(1,3)$ but here come my doubts. $A$ is not compact so I can't use Weierstrass' theorem? So how can I examine it?

Comment: Only an elementary approach.

Let $z = y - x$ so that $A = \{(x, z) | 0 \leqslant z \leqslant x\}$ and $g (x, z) := f(x, x + z) = x (z - 1) e^{-x - z}$. Your problem is equivalent to finding upper bound of the function $g (x, z)$ on $A$. Since $\log$ is continous, we can as well find the upper bound of $\log g$ and then exponentiate it. Let $D$ be the domain of $\log g (x, z)$. We have $$\log g (x, z) = \log x + \log (z - 1) - (x + z).$$ Since the last expression (the last paranthesis) on the RHS grows faster than the rest, we should minimize $x + z$ on $A \cap D$ to obtain the desired ...

Comment: ...  result. This happens when $z = 1 + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrarily small. This gives us $$\log x + \log \epsilon - (x + 1 + \epsilon).$$ Hence, the upper bound on $A$ is $$\epsilon x e^{-x - 1 - \epsilon}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that $f$ is bounded above on $\{y=c\}\cap A$ by very small positive numbers as $c\to \infty.$ This allows you to reduce to a compact subset of $A.$

Comment: Honestly i don't see it. You mean something like $f(x,c)=x(c-x-1)\cdot e^{-c}$ where c is fixed? Could you show me how to? I have a huge problem with that kind of tasks on exercises.